# How to prove this statement in calculus

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity

$f(x)$ derivative in $x=0$,and $f(0)=0$, I need to prove that there is a $g(x)$, that is Continuous in $x=0$, and $f(x)=xg(x)$.

what I did is $f'(x)=g(x)+xg'(x)\implies f'(0)=g(0)+0$, but I dont think that the solution is too simple  like this.

Answer (score 2):

Simply define$$g(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{f(x)}x&\text{ if }x\neq0\\f'(0)&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$and prove that $g$ is continuous at $0$.

Comment: but we need to prove that f(x)=x*g(x) as well

Comment: @sam0101 If $x=0$, then $f(0)=0=0\times g(0)$. Otherwise, $f(x)=x\times g(x)$ since $g(x)=\frac{f(x)}x$.